# Most performing way and how to include a google font in your web project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-fonts

how to I include a google font in my basic webproject?
I am setting up a regular webproject with html,css and js in visual studio code.

And besides what is the most performant way in doing so?
Using api or downloading the fonts?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brother, here's the way. Just add this line at top of your css file.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

div {
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

Comment: is this the most performant way or should I download the font and include into my project?

Comment: This is the most performant. Because Google will serve these fonts using CDN. That's why when a user hits your site, Google will send these fonts from the nearest server of the user.

Comment: One question remains, why wouldn't you use the <link> to embed the font into the html? 

I see you can do both, but is it necesserely?